# SQL Server Parameter Date Range Issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am using the following query to get the difference between two dates. The date ranges are tolling 12 months interval.

CY stand for Current year while PY stands for Previous Year. The dates in Current year are used to calculate the previous year dates

When I execute my query I have the following output, where the month is 11 and day 364. But I want my months to be twelve and the day 365 or (366 for leap year).

```
DECLARE @CY_StartDate date =CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-13, 0) AS DATE), 
        @CY_EndDate date =CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) AS DATE);    --- Rolling 12 months
DECLARE @PY_startDate date =DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@CY_StartDate),
        @PY_EndDate date =DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@CY_EndDate)

SELECT
        @CY_StartDate AS CY_Start,
        @CY_EndDate AS CY_End,
        @PY_StartDate AS PY_Start,
        @PY_EndDate AS PY_End,
        DATEDIFF(year, @CY_StartDate, @CY_EndDate) AS yr,
        DATEDIFF(month, @CY_StartDate, @CY_EndDate) AS month,
        DATEDIFF(day, @CY_StartDate, @CY_EndDate) AS day
```

Current Output

```
CY_Start     CY_End         PY_Start     PY_End     yr  month   day
2017-10-01   2018-09-30     2016-10-01  2017-09-30  1   11      364
```

Expected output

```
CY_Start     CY_End         PY_Start     PY_End     yr  month   day
2017-10-01   2018-09-30     2016-10-01  2017-09-30  1   12      365
```

Comment: 364 is the *correct* response. There are 364 days between those two dates, just like there is only one day between `2017-10-01' and '2017-09-30'. If you want to count the starting date in the difference, add 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you are getting make sense. `DATEDIFF` counts the ticks between 2 dates, where a tick is the value of the first parameter. So, for example: `DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20180101','20180228')` will return 1, as only 1 tick has occured (`2 - 1 = 1`). Seems, here, you simply need to add 1:

```
DECLARE @CY_StartDate date =CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-13, 0) AS DATE), 
        @CY_EndDate date =CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) AS DATE);    --- Rolling 12 months
DECLARE @PY_startDate date =DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@CY_StartDate),
        @PY_EndDate date =DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@CY_EndDate)

        select
        @CY_StartDate as CY_Start,
        @CY_EndDate AS CY_End,
        @PY_StartDate AS PY_Start,
        @PY_EndDate AS PY_End,

        DATEDIFF(year,@CY_StartDate,DATEADD(DAY,1,@CY_EndDate)) as yr,
        DATEDIFF(month,@CY_StartDate,DATEADD(DAY,1,@CY_EndDate)) as month,
        DATEDIFF(day,@CY_StartDate,DATEADD(DAY,1,@CY_EndDate)) as day
```

The reason I used a further `DATEADD` is because this makes it consistent with every expression. The value of `yr` was correct, however, for dates like `20170101` and `20171231`, the value of `yr` would be `0`. Hence adding 1 day the the value of `@CY_EndDate` makes this far more reliable, should the dates move.

Answer (score 2):

Common sense. How many numbers are there between 1 and 10 including both? You might say that there are 10 - 1 = 9 which is incorrect. The correct answer is (10 - 1) + 1 = 10.

Likewise, if you have two inclusive dates e.g. `2017-10-01` and `2018-09-30` you add one to `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-10-01', '2018-09-30')` to get 365 instead of 364.

However, as suggested in the other answer, it is much better to the end date exclusive (not counted) which makes date calculations straight forward. In your example, you should add 1 day to the last date so that you have `[2017-10-01, 2018-10-01)` and `DATEDIFF` will produce desired results.